# MySql Stored procedure/Loop inside a Entity Framework migration script

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, data-migration

So my problem is that i need a loop inside a Migration script to be able to transfer data into its new state.
However it dosn't seem as if it's possible to create a stored procedure inside the Sql statement in the migration script.

The following will result in a syntax error at the "DELIMITER"-part of the statement:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql(@"
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SomeProcedure(); 
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProcedure()
    BEGIN
        ...
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
    CALL SomeProcedure();
    ");
}
```

The statement runs fine inside MySql Workbench. So it must be EF way of handling the statements that causes the issue.

Now my question is: Is there any way at all to create a Stored procedure inside a migration script?

It seems to be DELIMITER causing the syntax error, but it's kind of impossible to create a stored procedure without it? (I'm using EF6)

I did try to split the Statements up, without any success. And i did try different delimiters as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alter Stored Procedure in DB Migration EF 6 Code First - how to pass through null as default for a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517164/alter-stored-procedure-in-db-migration-ef-6-code-first-how-to-pass-through-nul)

Answer (score 0):

It's posible to create a stored procedure with CreateStoredProcedure method.

```
CreateStoredProcedure(
        "dbo.Post_Insert",
        p => new
            {
                Title = p.String(),
                Text = p.String(),
            },
        body:
            @"INSERT [dbo].[Posts]([Title], [Text])
              VALUES (@Title, @Text)

              DECLARE @Id int
              SELECT @Id = [Id]
              FROM [dbo].[Posts]
              WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

              SELECT t0.[Id]
              FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS t0
              WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[Id] = @Id"
    );
```

More info here: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2013/12/23/EntityFramework6CodeFirstMigrations.aspx